# How to get the checkpoint Visible property for cell in TRVTableItemInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I am trying to get the `CPEventKind` property through the `TRVTableItemInfo`.
As I know that the Table cell is having `Inplace Editor` and we can add checkpoint
in the cell.

So is there any way to the `OnCheckpointVisible` event on display of `Checkpoint`
in cell of a `TRVTableItemInfo`.

**Note: I am using TRichView and adding TRVTableItemInfo in RichView**

Suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in Advance.